# Extract two date values from a string

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to extract two date values from a string.
I'm able to partially do it.
Note that the dates will be placed anywhere within the string.

```
DECLARE @Stringval VARCHAR(500);     

SET @Stringval = '2012-05-23 - hdfDice - somewhere - 5-23-12 Alpha';

IF ISDATE(SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 10)) = 1
BEGIN
  -- Shows first date of 2012-05-23 fine. Works!
  PRINT SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 10);
END

IF ISDATE(SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 7)) = 1
BEGIN
  -- DOES NOT EXTRACT THE SECOND DATE PROPERLY OF 5-23-12. It shows as 2-05-23
   PRINT SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 7);
END
```

Comment: How structured are these strings? Will these embedded dates always be found in the same place (relative or absolute), or is this just random data getting dumped on you?

Comment: Hello, the dates are not structured. They can be found anywhere within the string.

Comment: 5-23-12 is easy, what about 10-12-11? Is it October, November or December? What year?

Comment: @ZoharPeled can comment on how to extract the date. Also is there is a way to specify on how the date should map when converting to a date.  example M/D/YY, etc.

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to include some more sample data it would help. I'll try to post an answer tomorrow, if I'll find the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as a note to consider in your future questions, you've done a pretty good job posting your code, but you could have posted some more comprehensive sample data - we only get one example to work with, so mistakes are highly probable.

Here's a better example of sample data:

```
DECLARE @Strings As TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    StringVal VARCHAR(500)  
);

INSERT INTO @Strings (StringVal) VALUES
-- Both dates are valid
('2012-05-23 - hdfDice - somewhere - 5-23-12 Alpha'),
(' 5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha'),
('5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha'),
('15-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha'),
-- One date is invalid
('5-53-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha'),
('13-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha'),
('5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-33 Alpha'),
('5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-15-23 Alpha'),
('5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-1x-23 Alpha'),
('y-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha'),
-- both dates are invalid
('5-43-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-1x-23 Alpha'),
('y-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-15-23 Alpha');
```

Since you're attempting to extract two different formats, you will also need different styles to convert the different string representations to proper dates. Also, the second string format is kinda problematic since it might start with one or two digits (Note: I'm assuming that the other parts will always contain two digits - an assumption that you need to verify if you're going to use my suggested solution) - So I've used two different patterns to find it - one with two digits, and the other with a space and a digit.

The next step is to verify that the second date pattern will not match the first one (because that's the problem you're having in the first place) - so I've added `[^0-9]` to the beginning of the pattern that uses two digits.

Since by now I'm working with three different patterns and two different lengths and styles, I've decided to store that data in a table variable - like this:

```
DECLARE @Dates AS TABLE
(
    Pattern varchar(100),
    Length int,
    ConvertStyle int
)
INSERT INTO @Dates (Pattern, Length, ConvertStyle) VALUES
('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', 11, 120),
('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', 8, 10),
('% [0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', 8, 10);
```

Now all I had to do is a `cross join` the strings table to the dates table, and using a couple of `cross apply` to do the calculations, I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT    Id 
        , Stringval 
        , DateIndex
        , DateString 
        , DateValue
FROM @Strings
CROSS JOIN @Dates
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX(Pattern, ' '+ Stringval) As DateIndex) As foundIndex
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(DateIndex > 0, SUBSTRING(' '+ Stringval, DateIndex + 1, Length), NULL) As DateString) As extractedStrings
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CONVERT(Date, DateString, ConvertStyle) As DateValue) As extractedDates
WHERE DateValue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Id, DateIndex
```

Results:

```
Id  Stringval                                           DateIndex   DateString  DateValue
1   2012-05-23 - hdfDice - somewhere - 5-23-12 Alpha    1           2012-05-23  2012-05-23
1   2012-05-23 - hdfDice - somewhere - 5-23-12 Alpha    36          5-23-12     2012-05-23
2    5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha   2           5-23-12     2012-05-23
2    5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha   34          2012-05-23  2012-05-23
3   5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha    1           5-23-12     2012-05-23
3   5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha    33          2012-05-23  2012-05-23
4   15-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha   34          2012-05-23  2012-05-23
5   5-53-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha    33          2012-05-23  2012-05-23
6   13-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha   34          2012-05-23  2012-05-23
7   5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-33 Alpha    1           5-23-12     2012-05-23
8   5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-15-23 Alpha    1           5-23-12     2012-05-23
9   5-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-1x-23 Alpha    1           5-23-12     2012-05-23
10  y-23-12 - hdfDice - somewhere - 2012-05-23 Alpha    33          2012-05-23  2012-05-23
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>Rextester</kbd>](https://rextester.com/GLYM87931)